# How to embed trusted iframes after html sanitizing?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, html-sanitizing

If i use [google-caja html sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer)  with its default whitelist then it will not allow me to embed `iframe`.

I know it is a security risk that's why it is not allowing me to do this. But their are so many trusted website which provide functionality via `iframe` e.g. google maps,twitter button etc.

So please suggest me how can i implement trusted one to allow my user to use this functionality.